# Wrong barcode format from "python-barcode" library

Tags: python, pip, barcode

I am trying to print ean-13 format from python-barcode library but I keep getting incorrect format of the barcode.
I wrote the following code

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
ean = EAN(u'8906127480058', writer=ImageWriter())
fullname = ean.save('my_ean13_barcode')
```

The output was

[image]

Expected output is

[image]

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

The thirteenth number is a checksum. The software that generates the graphic may be confused by your addition of the 8. Try sending the 12 character string '890612748005' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked when i set barcode type to 'ean13-guard'

```py
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13-guard')
```